# What data-type is used for images?

Tags: c, python-3.x, image-processing, pyopencl

I was deriving NDVI (Normalized Difference Vegetation Index), which is a ratio of (NIR-R)/(NIR+R) where NIR is Near-Infrared band and R is Red band. This index ranges from -1 to 1. So I wrote a pyopencl code and here is what I have done and observed.

**Python code:**

```
import pyopencl as cl
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from time import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#get kernel file
def getKernel():
    kernel = open('kernel.c').read()
    return kernel

#return images as numpy int32 arrays
def convToArray(im_r,im_nir):
    a = np.asarray(im_r).astype(np.int32)
    b = np.asarray(im_nir).astype(np.int32)

    return a,b

#processing part
def getDerivation(platform,device,im_r,im_nir):

    #setting device
    pltfrm = cl.get_platforms()[platform]
    dev = pltfrm.get_devices()[device]
    cntx = cl.Context([dev])
    queue = cl.CommandQueue(cntx)

    #get 2Darrays
    r,nir = convToArray(im_r,im_nir)

    #shape of array
    x = r.shape[1]

    mf = cl.mem_flags

    bs = time()

    #input images buffer
    inR = cl.Buffer(cntx,mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR,hostbuf=r)
    inIR = cl.Buffer(cntx,mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR,hostbuf=nir)

    #output image buffers
    ndvi = cl.Buffer(cntx,mf.WRITE_ONLY,r.nbytes)

    be = time()
    print("Buffering time: " + str(be-bs) + " sec")
    ts = time()

    #load kernel
    task = cl.Program(cntx,getKernel()%(x)).build()

    #execute the process
    task.derive(queue,r.shape,None,inR,inIR,ndvi)

    #create empty buffer to store result
    Vout = np.empty_like(r)

    #dump output buffers to empty arrays
    cl.enqueue_copy(queue,Vout,ndvi)

    te = time()

    #convert arrays to gray - image compatible formate
    NDVI = Vout.astype(np.uint8)

    print("Processing time: " + str(te - ts) + " On: " + pltfrm.name + " --> " + dev.name)

    return NDVI

def process(platform,device,im_r,im_nir):
    NDVI,NDBI,NDWI = getDerivation(platform,device,im_g,im_r,im_nir,im_swir)
    print(NDVI)
    cv2.imshow("NDVI",NDVI)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    R = cv2.imread("BAND3.jpg",0)
    NIR = cv2.imread("BAND4.jpg",0)

    print(R.dtype) #returns uint8

    process(0,0,R,NIR) #(0,0) is my intel gpu
```

**kernel code(C):**

```
__kernel void derive(__global int* inR,__global int* inIR,__global int* ndvi){

    int x = get_global_id(0);
    int y = get_global_id(1);

    int width = %d;
    int index = x + y*width;

    //ndvi ratio (-1 to 1)

    int a = ((inIR[index] - inR[index])/(inIR[index] + inR[index])) * (256);

    a = (a <   (0) ?   (-1*a)  :   (a));
    a = (a >   (255) ?   (255) :   (a));

    ndvi[index] = (a);

}
```

**input image R:**[image: Red band image]

**input image NIR:** [image: Near-Infrared image]

**both the images have bit depth of 8**

BUT I GET JUST A BLANK IMAGE. I wrote the result on the command line for debugging reasons initially,
command line output:

```
(1151, 1151)
Buffering time: 0.015959739685058594 sec
Processing time: 0.22115755081176758 On: Intel(R) OpenCL --> Intel(R) HD Graphics 520
[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]
```

Now what i think is i may not be using proper datatype for the images? also, in the kernel the line `((inIR[index] - inR[index])/(inIR[index] + inR[index]))` will gives a float value, which i multiply with 256 to get a pixel value for that respective float value. So is it there the problem? Does any one know where i am going wrong?

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Why do you think you'll get a float? You'll get an int. Try casting the top or bottom to float before dividing.

Comment: @MarkSetchell `float num = (inIR[index] - inR[index]);
    float deno = (inIR[index] + inR[index]);
    int a = (int)((num/deno) * (256));` is this you talking about ?

Comment: Also, you probably don't want to multiply NDVI, which is in the range [-1,+1] by 256. You'd probably add 1 to bring it to range [0,2] and multiply by 127.5 to bring it to range [0,255].

Comment: `float num = (float)(inIR[index] - inR[index]);  
    float deno = (float)(inIR[index] + inR[index]);  
    int a = (int)(((num/deno)+1)*127.5);`  i did this, but the result is the same... blank array. Is it what you were talking about BTW ?

Comment: I can't try it for the moment, but try just using straight Numpy to compare. It's just one line `NDVI = (im_nir.astype(np.float)-im_r.astype(np.float))/...` then look at `NDVI.max()` and `NDVI.min()`.

Comment: Okay let me go with that ... I shall comment again if I have issues ... Thanks though ! @MarkSetchell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay ... i got it. I just changed the datatype in the line `a = np.asarray(im_r).astype(np.int32)` in the function `convToArray()` to `float32` and in the kernel file, i changed the parameter type to `float` and added  `int a = (int)((((float)(inIR[index] - inR[index])/(float)(inIR[index] + inR[index]))+1)*127.5);` for the calculation. However, ***i need an explaination***, why this worked and not the other way... I probably can think like, the result what we get after this calculation, `int` type loses data while conversion from `float`...is it?

Comment: `int` can only hold whole numbers... i.e. integers. There are only 3 integers in your range [-1,1] which are -1, 0 and 1. All fractional stuff gets lost.